# Converting a date array into an integer array

Tags: java

May I ask for some advice on this code. Basically I'm trying to convert the dates array into an integer array so I can find out the min and the max for the array.

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DateOfBirth {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int n;
        ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Set an array dimension");
        n = in.nextInt();

        String da[] = new String[n];
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy"); //issue found
        sdf.setLenient(false);
        Date date[] = new Date[n];
        in.nextLine();
        int[] convertite =new int[n];
        for (int i = 0; i < da.length; i++) {
            da[i] = in.nextLine();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < da.length; i++) {
            try {
                date[i] = sdf.parse(da[i]);
                System.out.println("dates are "+date[i]);

            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            }
        for (int i=0;i<da.length;i++){
            convertite[i]=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(date[i]));
            System.out.println("converted numbers are "+convertite[i]);
        }

        in.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: what type of advice do you want?

Comment: "I can find out the min and the max for the array." Dates are comparable, why not just sort the existing array? Also, what about the java.time api.

Answer (score -1):

If only to arrange you should try:

```
for (int i = 0; i < da.length; i++) {
        convertite[i] = (int) date[i].getTime();
        System.out.println("converted numbers are " + convertite[i]);
    }
```